# implementing interface methods c#

Tags: c#, interface

I need your help

I have this piece of code

```
 interface A
{
      void PrintFields();
}
class B : A
{
    int y;
    void  A.PrintFields()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("y = {0}", y);
    }
}
```

and  I have this

```
  interface A
{
      void PrintFields();
}
class B : A
{
    int y;
    public void PrintFields()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("y = {0}", y);
    }
}
```

}

so I am confused about the difference between those two different ways in implementing interface methods and why I can't use the public modifier in the first way.

Comment: This is called "explicit interface implementation" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Dennis_E  thanks a lot, could you put it as answer so I can accept it.